# How do I implement this Java program using hashmap and arrylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, implementation

In a  Kitchen are Cupboards and a Refrigerator, in each of the cupboard i can put and get out products  ( Cheese, milk and eggs)

Here is my Kitchen class which I used hashmap to create an instruction on how to go about getting the Cupboard and Refrigerator in the Kitchen;

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class  Kitchen{
    HashMap<String,KitchenCabinet > store = new HashMap<String, KitchenCabinet >();`

    public void  putKitchenCabinet (String name, `KitchenCabinet newKuechenSchrank) {
        store.put(name, newKitchenCabinet);
    }
    public KitchenCabinet getKitchenCabinet (String name){
        KitchenCabinet out = this.store.get(name);
        return out;
    }
}
```

I have also created a separate class for each of  the products  ( Cheese, milk and eggs) and created also an abstract Product class which extends to the other class of products, then I used an Arraylist in the class KitchenCabinet

Here is my KitchenCabinet class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public  class KitchenCabinet {

    //List of Products here 
    Products vaildProducts;

    ArrayList<Products> superProducts = new ArrayList<Products>();

    public void addProducts(Products myProducts) {
        this.superProducts.add(myProducts);
    }

    public Products getProducts() {
        Products out = this.superProducts.remove(0);
        return out;
    }
}
```

How do i implement the following?

1. Kitchen has 2 cabinet layers (Left, Right and Refrigerator)
2. 2x Cheese inside the refrigerator
3. 2x Milk in the Left
4. 3x milk in the Right
5. 1x Egg in the Left

And Question

- How many products are in the Kitchen.
- How many Milk are in the Kitchen.
- In which Cabinet is Product X.

Please anybody, I need your help to implement this program.
I am very new to programming and in between, I'm lost. Thanks so much in advance

Comment: You just asked us to do your homework. Not the right place for that. If you want help, you should start by stating what exactly is your problem, what you do not understand.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser for the responds, My problem is that I don't know how to go about it, a guideline would help a lot.

Comment: Shortly. Kitchen has 3 maps where first parameter is name and second is arraylist for 2 cabinet layers and refrigerator. This should be enough advice for succesfull completion of your homework

Comment: Thanks, But can anyone write out the codes for me, as I have been working on this for almost a week now and till not getting it right.

Comment: If you are unable to transform my advice in code then grab some book study. Then come back on SO if something specific isnt working and post what have you done so far. you wont find here anyone who will solve whole HW for you

Answer (score 0):

So here is a solution for what you showed. I would advise you to not submit this answer as your homework, as your teacher will probably check the Internet for students seeking help. Use it as starting point for your own, better implementation, as this is only rough draft.

Important to note, look up some naming conventions for java. For instance classes are often singular, while collections plural (it is up to discussion, sure). When you are working with more complicated design, correct naming helps you orientate in your code.

Use diamond notation (available in java 7 I think?) for your collections, as it makes your lines shorter and clearer.

```
//do
HashMap<String,Storage> storages = new HashMap<>();
//don't
HashMap<String,Storage> storages = new HashMap<String,Storage>();
```

When you have dedicated class for something, hide its members using private keyword, especially if you don't plan to access it directly, nor should you want to do that for most cases.

Keep an eye on overengineering of your programs. For instance, in code below, it was not necessary to create new class for each product, and usually no programmer would do it, since those classes do not add any functionality whatsoever, and only increase readability of code.

Do not implement things you do not need. In you example, you implemented method that removes item from kitchen, which is not required by set tasks. That does not mean it is bad for exercise purposes, but usually it is waste of time and half of the methods you think you will need will need to be changed or will not be used at all.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class KitchenTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //initialize furniture
        Kitchen kitchen = new Kitchen();
        kitchen.createStorage("Refrigerator");
        kitchen.createStorage("Left Cabinet");
        kitchen.createStorage("Right Cabinet");

        //put products in the kitchen
        kitchen.put("Refrigerator", new Cheese());
        kitchen.put("Refrigerator", new Cheese());
        kitchen.put("Left Cabinet", new Milk());
        kitchen.put("Left Cabinet", new Milk());
        kitchen.put("Left Cabinet", new Egg());
        kitchen.put("Right Cabinet", new Milk());
        kitchen.put("Right Cabinet", new Milk());
        kitchen.put("Right Cabinet", new Milk());

        //how many products in the kitchen
        Map<String, List<Product>> contents = kitchen.find(null);
        int amount = 0;
        for (List<Product> value : contents.values()) {
            amount+=value.size();
        }
        System.out.println("In the kitchen is "+amount+" products.");

        //how many milk bottles
        contents = kitchen.find("Milk");
        amount = 0;
        for (List<Product> value : contents.values()) {
            amount+=value.size();
        }
        System.out.println("In the kitchen is "+amount+" milk bottles.");

        //in which cabinet is what
        contents = kitchen.find(null);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Product>> entry : contents.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("In "+entry.getKey()+" is "+Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().toArray()));
        }
    }
}

class Kitchen{
    private final HashMap<String,Storage> storages = new HashMap<>();

    public void  createStorage(String name) {
        storages.put(name, new Storage());
    }

    public void put(String storageName, Product product){
        if(!storages.containsKey(storageName)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Storage not found!");
        }
        storages.get(storageName).put(product);
    }

    //find specific product occurence in all storages
    public Map<String, List<Product>> find(String productName){
        Map<String, List<Product>> found = new HashMap<>();
        for (String storageName : storages.keySet()) {
            found.put(storageName, storages.get(storageName).find(productName));
        }
        return found;
    }
}

//generic storage place, there is no functional difference between refrigerator
//and cabinets
class Storage {
    private final ArrayList<Product> contents = new ArrayList<>();

    public void put(Product myProducts) {
        this.contents.add(myProducts);
    }

    //iterate over all contents of storage and storages found items in list
    public List<Product> find(String name) {
        List<Product> found = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Product product : contents) {
            //if you put name as null, you will get all products in the storage
            if(name==null || product.name.equals(name)){
                found.add(product);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}

//recognized products by name and class
class Product{
    public final String name;
    public Product(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){return name;}
}
class Milk extends Product{public Milk(){super("Milk");}}
class Cheese extends Product{public Cheese(){super("Cheese");}}
class Egg extends Product{public Egg(){super("Egg");}}
```

Hope it helps,
Regards.

Comment: Oh Kaiser, Thanks a Trillion times because you just saved me  from days of frustration, been working on this for days and the more i try, the more confused i get, I'm only about 5 weeks ago into this world of programming.This guidelines are just what i need to implement mine, with this I know exactly how to go about it. Please, i would like to have a few words with you if you don't mind can you drop me your phone number to my email, fitiowe at yahoo.com. Thanks.

Comment: *"You just asked us to do your homework. Not the right place for that. "* Really? You just did his homework, so why isn't this the right place?

Comment: @Tom, i understand he was only trying at first to let me know that i have to do my assignment myself and not give it out to others to workout  for me, but letting him know that I needed some guideline  to work it out myself was the reason he did what he did.

Comment: @Vojtěch Kaiser thanks again. I am working my own implemented. I will try to post it on here after i am done. please send me an email, have dropped you my address earlier.

Comment: @Tom I get that, but as I stated in the answer, he can't use this code for his assignment, he has to understand it first, and then make it different. Such example can significantly speed up the learning process, especially with commentary what he did wrong in his attempt. But I definitely get why I look like hypocrite to you, at first I indeed did not intend to implement the assignment.

Comment: @VojtěchKaiser I guess I just have too much bad experience with new users who ask for help _and code_ to do the own homeworks. Later they "promise" to learn from it, but in the end they just copy&paste it and come back later with more "gimme the codez" questions. But I don't know if Nicholas is like them. Hopefully not. (btw: Stackoverflow also has a name for that behavior: [Help Vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire))

Comment: **implementation** I meant to say, excuse me

Comment: @Tom I am not like every other *new users* who just need someone to work their homework. I am learning Java programming at the moment and I'm learning it myself from reading books and online videos of courses, i get help from an expert programmer but he barely has time for me, he explains to me if I have  questions and he gives me  exercises like that i posted  earlier, I did it all myself to that stage. I'm very new to programming and i am very determine to learn. I can't say all on here. If anyone is ready to also assist me also or guide me through. You are very welcome. Thanks so much.

Comment: @VojtěchKaiser, I implemented the hashcode and equals to the class storage so i don't get the same value at output but it won't work. Can you please look into it? I have edited the program with my code.